# Can the default databases shipped with a new Snowflake account be deleted?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake ships with a number of databases - which of the following are ok to delete and which are critical for operations to retain?

[image showing databases DEMO_DB, UTIL_DB, SNOWFLAKE, and SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdaiw.png)

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all of them except for `SNOWFLAKE`. Snowflake the company/service is actually the owner of the `SNOWFLAKE` database so you couldn't delete that even if you tried, but you can delete all other databases using the right ROLE without any issues as they just have sample data in them.

The `SNOWFLAKE` database is extremely useful as it keeps a history of all Queries and other activity within your account.